# Check if wifi printer is busy&printing queue on android 4.2

Tags: android, printing, android-wifi, thermal-printer

I have a `selphy` cp1200 printer by cannon, its a **wifi** ipp printer, i wish to print to it using an app I created in android studio, my problem is **no** printing software I used was able to queue prints, which means I could only print one page and then had to wait until the printer wasnt busy to send another print. My question is can I check if the **wifi** printer is busy. or alternetivly you could suggest an android app that supports queued printing I've used printer2go, printershare,lets print Droid,the cannon print app and lots more and none of them were able to queue printing which lead me to belive the android version I'm using wasn't supporting the queuing feature**(Android 4.2)** if you could confirm this I will upgrade my android.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Android did not support native printing before 4.4 (Kitkat) .. Prior to this version you'd need to use an app (as you already did), it may be printer related but it doesn't seem to be Android related since Android 4.2 wouldn't do any printer queuing, it's the app